# jQuery Tags Manager & Typeahead: prevent input from beeing filled after leaving the input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm using this jQuery Plugin together with twitter-typeahead:

https://maxfavilli.com/jquery-tag-manager

Everything works as expected, there is only one little thing that bothers me:

After selecting one or multiple tags, leaving the input field shows the last tag inside the input field. And I could not figure out why/how and how to prevent that.

The process happens like this:

1. user clicks into tag manager input
2. user starts typing, gets auto-completion
3. user selects an auto-completion item
4. the item gets added as tag, the input field gets emptied
5. user clicks outside of the input field, the input field gets filled with the last selected tag => WHY??!
   (desired outcome: input field stays empty after leaving)

You can tryout yourself on the tags-manager website I linked above, just go to the example

**"Using tag manager in conjunction with typeahead.js"**

and enter a country name, select the country, then leave the input field.

I already tried this: [How to prevent Twitter typeahead from filling in the input with the selected value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24417527/how-to-prevent-twitter-typeahead-from-filling-in-the-input-with-the-selected-val), but unfortunately it does not help, since the tag gets filled into the input field after leaving the input - typeahead is closed already then.

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group mbn">
    <label for="artikel_person">Person</label>
    <input id="artikel_person" placeholder="E-Mail- oder Namensbestandteil" class="gui-input tm-input" type="text">
    <input name="artikel_person" id="artikel_person-out" type="hidden">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 tag-container tags-artikel_person">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var th_config = {
        hint: true,
        highlight: true,
        minLength: 1
    };
var artikel_person = [];
var artikel_personApi = $("#artikel_person").tagsManager({
            delimiters: [13, 44, 59],
            backspace: [],
            tagsContainer: '.tags-artikel_person',
            tagClass: 'tm-tag-system',
            onlyTagList: true,
            fillInputOnTagRemove: false
        }).typeahead(th_config, {
            source: ajaxPerson
        }).on('typeahead:selected', function (e, d) {
            artikel_personApi.tagsManager("pushTag", d.value);
            var index = artikel_person.findIndex(function (elem) {
                return elem.name === d.value;
            });
            if (index < 0) {
                artikel_person.push({name: d.value, id: d.id});
            }
            console.log("Typeahead selected. Input value: " + $(this).val()); // logs out empty
        }).on('tm:spliced', function (e, tag) {
            var index = artikel_person.findIndex(function (elem) {
                return elem.name === tag;
            });
            if (index > -1) {
                artikel_person.splice(index, 1);
            }
        }).on('typeahead:closed', function (obj, datum, name) {
            console.log("Typeahead closed. Input value: " + $(this).val()); // logs out empty
        });
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: @Leopard I don't think it will help with the problem, but I added the code.

Comment: Have you tried `$(obj.currentTarget).val("");` in `'typeahead:closed'` ?

Comment: Yes I did - as I said, the tag gets filled back in after the user leaves the input field, typeahead is closed already then.

Comment: @user2415266 can you add a Jsfiddle with minimum setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if the solution is this simple, But I tested by injecting this script into the documentation site and into the example under *`"Using tag manager in conjunction with typeahead.js"`*  and got it working fine.

Just add this into your scripts.

```
$("#artikel_person").on('blur',function(){
  $(this).val('');  // on focusing out of input remove the value in it..
});
```

Also make sure to bind this event after all the plugin initialization scripts.

**For live test**.. Go to the same documentation site and to same example and open the console tab, Paste this code and run it.

```
jQuery(".tm-input.tm-input-typeahead").on('blur',function(){$(this).val('');});
```

After this use the example and you can see the desired behavior.

Comment: @user2415266 glad I could help.. happy coding!!

Comment: @Danmoreng Will you award the bounty? Just a FYI even if you don't award you will loose the 100reps .. :)

Comment: @RajshekarReddy - If the bounty is not awarded manually, it will be awarded automatically to the accepted answer at the end of the grace period, if the answer was accepted during the bounty period. It is in fact awarded "some time" after the end of the grace period (about one hour).

Comment: @RajshekarReddy when I accepted your answer, I couldn't award the bounty yet (20 hours before you can ward...). That's the only reason I didn't until now.