# How to prevent typeahead from filling in the input with the selected value?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, bootstrap-typeahead

I am using bootstrap-typeahead and rails4.

I can get the dropdown feature but when I press up and down, I don't want the selected value to fill in the input. How can I implement this?

I tried some solutions but they didn't work.
[How to prevent Twitter typeahead from filling in the input with the selected value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24417527/how-to-prevent-twitter-typeahead-from-filling-in-the-input-with-the-selected-val)

Relevant code:

```
$("#nav_search").typeahead({
  items: 6,
  source:numbers.ttAdapter(),
  displayText: function(data){
      // console.log(data);
      return '<div><strong>'+data.username+'</strong>'+'-'+data.position+' at '+data.company+'</div>';
  },
  fitToElement: true,
  afterSelect: function(data){
    window.location.href=data.url;
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve it using

```
.on('keyup', this, function (event){
  if(event.which==38 || event.which==40) $(#nav_search).val(...)}
);
```

Comment: You can also access it by event.target.previousSibling